# What is the business of Session.Clear() in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

What does Session.Clear() do in NHibernate? I mean, what is the meaning of Clear in session?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- It will clear the unit of work (if you have unflushed changes, they will be discarded)
- It will remove all current entities in the session from the identity map, in effect it will be as if you called session.Evict on all instances loaded through this session.

Not sure what else.